# run-time error 13 with code - Clearing Contents of cells

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

Currently I have a spreadsheet running that tells me if an Associate is choosen for the trip. When I clear contents on one cell I am fine but if I clear more than one cell at a time I get a  run-time error 13. Is there any way to remove this error?

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim res As Variant
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A5:A550")) Is Nothing Then
    res = Application.CountIfs(Range("A5:A550"), Target, _
            Range("M5:M550"), "Associate")
    If Not IsError(res) Then
        If res > 0 Then MsgBox "You have choosen an associate for this trip!"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What would you want to happen if multiple cells are cleared in one operation?  How should it be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim res As Variant, c as Range, rng as Range, i as long

Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A5:A550"))

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    i=0
    For each c in rng.cells
        res = Application.CountIfs(Range("A5:A550"), c.Value, _
                                   Range("M5:M550"), "Associate")
        If Not IsError(res) Then 
            If res > 0 Then i = i + 1
        End If
    Next c

    If i > 0 Then 
       MsgBox "You have chosen an associate for " & _
                 IIf(i=1,"this trip!", i & " of these trips!")
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim Williams for the help. The clear contents allowing the cells to be cleared without an error is what I wanted (as you completed).

Answer (score 0):

Another option that worked for me is exiting the Sub in the event that a user clears multiple cells, or autofills multiple cells.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Target.Parent.Range("A5:A550")

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

// Put your code here
```